# git-svn fetch gives me a filename that git doesn't handle

Tags: windows, git

Using `git svn fetch` to do some local work (using git personally), I got a file that will not "reset".  I see that it's different from similar files in the same directory in that it has a backslash as part of the name: `icon@2xios8\.png`.  I suppose the backslash doesn't do anything on other platforms but msysgit on Windows 10 complains that it's unable to create the file.

I can't figure out how to make git ignore this subdirectory and let me continue with unrelated work.  But I really need to fix it somehow so git can be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `git-read-tree` and *sparse checkout* ([git-read-tree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree)).

Therefore you call

```
git config core.sparsecheckout true
```

Then create a file `.git/info/sparse-checkout` (with `touch .git/info/sparse-checkout` in msysgit bash). Edit this file and change its content to:

```
/*
!icon@2xios8\\.png
```

This tells git to look at all files in your working directory (`/*`) but *'!icon@2xios8.png'* (`!icon@2xios8\\.png`). Notice the escaped backslash here (`\\`)!

After you run `git read-tree -mu HEAD` you should be able to pull your repository by ignoring that specific file.